# How to Get a Count of Records Using Partitioning in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, window-functions

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    F.IID, 
    F.E_NUM AS M_E_NUM, 
    MCI.E_NUM AS MCI_E_NUM, 
    F.C_NUM AS M_C_NUM, 
    MCI.C_NUM AS MCI_C_NUM,
    F.ET_ID AS M_ET_ID, 
    EDIE.ET_ID AS ED_INDV_ET_ID,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY F.IID) IID_COUNT
FROM FT_T F JOIN CEMEI_T MCI ON F.IID = MCI.IID
    JOIN EDE_T EDE ON MCI.E_NUM = EDE.E_NUM
    JOIN EDIE_T EDIE ON EDIE.IID = F.IID AND EDIE.ET_ID = EDE.ET_ID
WHERE 
    F.DEL_F = 'N'
    AND MCI.EFF_END_DT IS NULL
    AND MCI.TOS = 'BVVB'
    AND EDE.PTEND_DT IS NULL
    AND EDE.DEL_S = 'N'
    AND EDE.CUR_IND = 'A'
    AND EDIE.TAR_N = 'Y'
    AND F.IID IN
        (
         SELECT DISTINCT IID 
         FROM FT_T 
         WHERE GROUP_ID = 'BG' 
            AND DEL_F = 'N' 
            AND (IID, E_NUM) NOT IN 
                (
                 SELECT IID, E_NUM FROM CEMEI_T 
                 WHERE TOS = 'BVVB' AND EFF_END_DT IS NULL
                )
        );
```

I am basically grabbing information from several tables and creating a flat record of them.

Everything works accordingly except now I need to find out whether there are two records in `FT_T` table with identical `IID`'s and display that count as part of the result set.

I tried to use partitioning but all the rows in the result set return a single count even though there are ones that have 2 records with identical `IID`'s in `FT_T`.

The reason I initially said that I'm gathering information from several tables is due to the fact that `FT_T` might not have all the information I need if two records are not available for the same `IID`, so I have to retrieve them from other tables `JOIN`ed in the query. However, I need to know which `FT_T.IID`'s have two records in `FT_T` (or greater than one).

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to calculate the count before the `join` and filtering:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT F.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY F.IID) as IID_CNT
      FROM FT_T F
     ) JOIN
     CEMEI_T MCI
     ON F.IID = MCI.IID JOIN
     EDE_T EDE
     ON MCI.E_NUM = EDE.E_NUM JOIN
     EDIE_T EDIE
     ON EDIE.IID = F.IID AND EDIE.ET_ID = EDE.ET_ID
 . . .
```

Comment: That makes sense, however, I just realized that my partition should, not only be over `F.IID`, but also a hard coded value from some other column, e.g. F.TYPE = 'A' as there might be multiple rows with the identical `F.IID`'s but I should only consider the ones in my window with `F.TYPE='A'`. Is there a way to include conditions in the partition window?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps throw that in the WHERE clause of that partition window subquery! But I guess the count is still going to be over all `TYPE`'s, no?

Comment: @NuCradle . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask, and the question is about counting `F.IID`.

Answer (score 0):

this is merely a comment/observation, but formatting is needed

You use of `in(...)` with `select distinct` and `not in(...,...)` seems complex and could be a problem if some values are NULL. I suggest you consider using EXISTS and NOT EXISTS instead. e.g.

```
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM FT_T
    WHERE F.IID = FT_T.IID
    AND FT_T.GROUP_ID = 'BG'
    AND FT_T.DEL_F = 'N'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM CEMEI_T
        WHERE FT_T.IID = CEMEI_T.IID
        AND FT_T.E_NUM = CEMEI_T.E_NUM
        AND CEMEI_T.TOS = 'BVVB'
        AND CEMEI_T.EFF_END_DT IS NULL
    )
)
```